# Vandermonde Determinant, a proof for a variant and some relating questions

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation

For $x_0,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ is

$V(x_0,...,x_n)=$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & ...........x_{0}^{n} \\
1 & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & ...........x_{1}^{n} \\
. & x_{2} & x_{2}^2 & ...........x_{2}^{n} \\
. & . & . &...........x_{3}^{n} \\
. & . & . & ...........x_{4}^{n} \\
. & . & . & \\
. & . & .\\
. & . & .\\
1 & x_n & x^{2}_n & ...........x_{n}^{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}

1. How can i show now that det $V(x_0,...,x_n) = \prod_{0 \leq i <j\leq n} (x_j - x_i)$? Would be enough for $n=0,1,2$ but a general approach would be nice. I know the proof of this but only starting at $x_1$. Could I do just an indexshift?
2. How can I with 1. now proof that wiht $n+1$ datapoints $(x_i,f_i)$ there is just one polynomial $p(x)$ with deg$\leq n$ (polynomial interpolation)
   And can that degree be any number between 0 and n? Are there examples?

Comment: 1) Try using induction and properties of the determinant. 2) What does the determinant tell you about a matrix? For your second question, surely if I give you 100 pts $(a,a^2)$, $0\leq a\leq 99$, there's only one polynomial that goes through them; what's its degree?

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more? i sometimes need a bit more time for that :)